# How to use a backup SQL Server driver in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS Access frontend that connects to a SQL Server backend.  Some of my users have the

> SQL Server Native Client 11.0

driver, and the rest only have the default

> SQL Server

driver.  Is there a way to have tables with the 'Native driver if present, and use the standard SQL Server driver if not?

Comment: Can you share more about the display problem?  It may be orthogonal to the driver.  It could also be that the “simple” odbc driver is so old it does not know about numeric types and is downconverting to real or similar

Comment: Please reword your question `"Is there a way to have tables without the 13 driver default or backup to the standard SQL Server driver?"`  Do you mean *"Is there a way to have all systems use the `SQL Driver` instead of the `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server`"*?  Also, in answering Conors question, do you have the Decimal display problem only for systems with the "13 driver"?

Comment: Users can enter a long decimal into the field tied to Decimal(18,17), and it saves to the precision entered.  I've verified it on the server.  However, when the user mouses away, the percentage is always rounded to two decimal points regardless of how many decimal points I tell Access to display.  When I use ODBC 13 or SQL Server Native Client 11.0, it displays properly.  The simple "SQL Server", default driver refuses to work.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to expand. Both the “legacy” Sql Driver, and the Native driver are able to pull, and render decimal types.

You can “test” this by flipping the linked table (from access) into design view. Answer yes to the “read only” prompt, and now view the data types of the columns and settings.

With the “older” driver you should see this:

[image]

So access is most certainly rendering and seeing the column as correct, and I am using the “older” sql driver.

However, to answer your question? You can run some re-link code on start up, but there is certainly no means to have Access auto matic “flip” between the drivers without VBA code to re-link the tables. So your code would check for "13" missing and then run VBA re-link code with older SQL Driver.

However, I would STRONG suggest against such an approach. Either stick to native 13, or stick to SQL driver. If you going to adopt native 13, then you have to simply ensure that driver is installed.

You NEVER want to flip between drivers, since this can introduce all kinds of errors, rounding and a whole bunch of issues that may well result in your application failing, or WORSE you entering the wrong data formats. All your building, testing, debugging will have been done with 13, and now your changing the rules (you not know if everything works with the older driver, and thus not catch bugs etc. while you build the application).

So, you could in theory on Access start up check for native 13 driver(s), and if not found, then you would have to check your links, and run some VBA code to use the older driver.

However, before you do this, I would attempt to figure out why Access is not seeing the decimal column – it should (with either driver).

However, what does NOT work is the newer datetime2 columns with that older/original sql driver.

If you use the “older” driver, access will see that date/time columns as strings, and that will REALLY mess up any forms or VBA code that attempts to enter, query or use date/time values.

So decimals should come through ok, but datetime2 columns will not with the older driver.

Driver cannot auto flip for you, but Access on start-up + VBA code to re-link is possible, but I don’t recommend this idea.

Comment: You will need two code routines. The first one is to re-link tables to SQL server. There is "tons" of examples  (Google this).  So lots of re-link code examples. Next up, is grab some code to read the registry (again, lots off examples). So you can check for the existence of a registry key for 13. I don't have the 13 key name, but they should follow the same format as outline here: http://www.mickgenie.com/how-to-check-the-version-of-sql-server-native-client/